# Is there a -ffast-math flag equivalent for the Visual Studio C++ compiler

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-2013, compiler-optimization, fast-math

I'm working with the default C++ compiler (I guess it's called the "Visual Studio C++ compiler") that comes with Visual Studio 2013 with the flag `/Ox` ([Full Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321(v=vs.71).aspx)). Due to floating point side effects, I must disable the `-ffast-math` flag when using the `gcc` compiler. Is there an equivalent option for this flag in the configuration of the Visual Studio C++ compiler?

Comment: Note that disabling `-ffast-math` in gcc means not passing that option, it is more like "not enabling".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for `/fp:precise`, although that is also the default.

If you need the strictest floating point calculations that VS can offer, try `/fp:strict`, although that is probably overkill.

You probably have nothing to worry about since the default behavior should be what you desire. Just make sure that `/fp:fast` is not specified, but if you try to compile with both `/fp:fast` and `/fp:precise` you will get a compilation error anyway, so that should be easy to catch.

The link that Hans Passant provided to the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) provides all the details you might want.

Answer (score -3):

None of the MSVC++ options enable the optimizations which are invoked by g++ `-ffast-math`.

Comment: are you sure? how about `/fp:`?

Comment: Microsoft /fp:fast doesn't invoke those optimizations.  You may be confused by the conflicting Intel C++ usage where fast=2 does operate similar to g++ -ffast-math ( and fast=1 invokes the important ones, except for complex limited range).

Comment: obviously it may not be exactly the same but it does specify the floating-point operations behavior **which is what the OP asked**. He didn't ask about all `-ffast-math` side effects

Comment: Does `-ffast-math` included in `-O3` in GCC? Because it seems in my project ([Image Convolution](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/ImageConvolution)) that MSVC 2015 generate much faster code than GCC 7.1.

Comment: No,. -O3 doesn't set -ffast-math.